# Are caraway seeds and fennel seeds the same?

Tags: seeds

My mom always called the seeds in rye bread caraway. But they are in Italian sausage and a jar labeled fennel seeds.

Are they the same thing?

Comment: Note that your mom was most probably right: the seeds in a seeded rye bread are caraway, never fennel.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fennel and caraway are relatives, but not the same plant.  Fennel seeds have a flavor dominated by anise/licorice, where caraway is quite different, being dominated by other flavors. They also have subtle differences in appearance.

Cumin, anise, and dill are other look-alike seeds with very different flavors.  Anise and fennel have very similar flavors, and can be substituted for each other.  Caraway and dill are likewise similar in flavor.  Cumin has a flavor different from any of the above. I am including pictures of fennel, caraway, anise, cumin, and dill seeds so you can see how similar they are, but also how there are subtle differences in shape.

**Fennel Seed:**

[image: Fennel seeds picture]

**Caraway Seeds:**

[image: Caraway Seeds picture]

**Anise Seed:**  It is hard to tell from the picture, but anise seeds are much smaller than fennel.
[image: Anise Seed]

**Cumin Seeds:** note, these vary considerably in color
[image: Cumin seeds picture]

**Dill Seeds:** (note how much flatter theses are)

[image: Dill seed picture]

Comment: and also caraway seeds are tasty, can't say the same for fennel!

Comment: To add to the confusion: Shahi Jeera  :)

Answer (score 4):

They are related, but not the same plant. Wikipedia also calls Caraway "meridian fennel", which hints as to how related they are.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caraway), Caraway is in the Apiaceae family, along with anise, fennel, cumin, licorice-root, and coriander.

Comment: I tend to think of fennel as having a more pure anise/licorice flavor, where caraway has other flavor notes, and isn't completely dominated by anise flavor.

Comment: @BobMcGee I agree, that's the difference between them.

Comment: You know what... I really should have posted that as an answer.